# last statement of procedure after for loop is not working in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have created following test procedure, where i am printing debug message, i fount that last statement of procedure after for loop is not working. why ?

in following case, i am not able to print debug message of third for loop, you can find result after procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SCRIPT AS 
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- Before for loop --');

  for rec in (
    SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
  ) loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- inside for loop --');
  end loop;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- after for loop --');

  for rec in (
    SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
  ) loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- second loop --');
  end loop;

  for rec in (
    SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
  ) loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- third loop --');
  end loop;


END TEST_SCRIPT;
```

result:

```
-- Before for loop --
-- inside for loop --
-- after for loop --
-- second loop --
Process exited.
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

instead of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind that output is that, [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i999434) places line in buffer and your call to  `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE()` returned line placed in buffer.

So, here your `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- Before for loop --');` is returned by `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE()` call which you mentioned in first for loop.

And similarly, same thing happened for other calls and since `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE()` is absent for `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- third loop --');`
and so it didn't get printed.

To get it printed just change below--

```
.....

for rec in (
    SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
  ) loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- third loop --');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  end loop;
..
```

Answer (score 2):

Its actually executing Third loop as well  You need to add    `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();` after  `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- third loop --');`

Answer (score 2):

Modify your last loop like below.

```
  for rec in (
    SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
  ) loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- third loop --');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  end loop;
```

**Reason**:

Untill DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE() calls then only the data will be display present in put buffer.

**Edit**

By editing your code..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SCRIPT AS 
BEGIN


  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- Before for loop --');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  for rec in (
    SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
  ) loop

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- inside for loop --');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  end loop;


  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- after for loop --');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  for rec in (
    SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
  ) loop

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- second loop --');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  end loop;

  for rec in (
    SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL
  ) loop

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('-- third loop --');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  end loop;
END TEST_SCRIPT;
```

Comment: For a cursor query that gets more than one row - which hopefully the OP really has, otherwise why loop - putting the extra `new_line` inside the loop would give blank lines; it would be cleaner to have a final one *after* the loop? Or change all the loops to only have `new_line` right at the end; not clear if there's a reason to do it like this, and not to use `put_line`.